# Error apt-get update on Kali Linux System

Tags: apt, kali-linux

I am trying to update the system, but the following error appears, what should I do?

```
apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Err:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
  Redirection loop encountered
Err:3 https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  Could not connect to proxy:443 (103.224.182.210). - connect (111:Connection refused)
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release'no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: What is the system you're on?

Comment: system kali linux

Answer (score 1):

you have two issues:

1) Err:1 https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease and

2) Err:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release

To fix the 1st issue:

3) Edit your /etc/apt/sources.list and change from deb https://http.kali.org/kali  to deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free

To fix the 2nd issue:

4) Edit your /etc/apt/sources.list and remove http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb , saved and update your apt.

For more details see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100734/error-apt-get-update